# How can I view all Trello Cards that have a link to a particular Trello Card?

Tags: trello

If I get the *Link To This Card* and then paste that into another Card, how can I see all the Cards that have such a link (to this card) on them?

I tried searching on the *Link To This Card*, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can do this by using the board search with the URL of the card that you're concerned about (without the https).  From what I can tell, this only works using the search box at the top of the page and doesn't work when using the filters on a board.

For example, if I want to find cards that have links to `https://trello.com/c/mIkC5aTy`, searching for `trello.com/c/mIkC5aTy` shows me the cards that have links to that one.